# How to pass props to row in react-table

Tags: reactjs, react-table, react-table-v7

I've been following https://blog.logrocket.com/complete-guide-building-smart-data-table-react/. To apply custom styling depending on cell value, I'm updating the column object like so:

```
return {
  Header: key,
  accessor: key,
  width: "150",
  sortType: "basic",
  Cell: ({cell: {value} }) => {
    if (value == "Error") {
      return <RedCell/>
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

Is it possible instead to apply custom styling to the row containing the cell? I guess a prop would have to be passed down to row, but am just not clear at all on how to do this.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

For anyone stumbling upon this issue, this has been answered by the author of the `react-table` library here — [https://spectrum.chat/react-table/general/v7-row-getrowprops-how-to-pass-custom-props-to-the-row~ff772376-0696-49d6-b259-36ef4e558821](https://spectrum.chat/react-table/general/v7-row-getrowprops-how-to-pass-custom-props-to-the-row%7Eff772376-0696-49d6-b259-36ef4e558821)

In your Table component, you pass on any prop (say, `rowProps`) of your choice for rows —

```
<Table
        columns={columns}
        data={data}
        rowProps={row => ({
          onClick: () => alert(JSON.stringify(row.values)),
          style: {
            cursor: "pointer"
          }
        })}
      />
```

Then to actually use this —

```
function Table({ columns, data, rowProps = () => ({}) }) {
  // Use the state and functions returned from useTable to build your UI
  const { getTableProps, headerGroups, rows, prepareRow } = useTable({
    columns,
    data
  });

  // Render the UI for your table
  return (
    <table {...getTableProps()}>
      <thead>
        {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
          <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
            {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
              <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>{column.render("Header")}</th>
            ))}
          </tr>
        ))}
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {rows.map(
          (row, i) =>
            prepareRow(row) || (
              <tr {...row.getRowProps(rowProps(row))}>
                {row.cells.map(cell => {
                  return (
                    <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render("Cell")}</td>
                  );
                })}
              </tr>
            )
        )}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently you are applying styling to your columns definitions.

In order to apply styling to an entire Row. (eg. make the entire row red if value == "Error"), I would do it in your table UI.

In your UI you are going to be calling `prepareRow(row)` and then using the row to render the cells.

maybe with : `row.cells.map`

At this point you could do something different based on the content of a cell `row.cells[0]`

maybe something like this:

```
                  {(row.cells[0].value !== "Error" && row.cells.map(cell =>
                    {
                        return (
                            <TableCell {...cell.getCellProps({ className: cell.column.className })}>
                                {cell.render('Cell')}
                            </TableCell>
                        );
                    })) ||  <RedRow />}
```